# SAML signature verification using Python/M2Crypto

Tags: python, m2crypto, saml-2.0

I'm attempting to use M2Crypto to verify a signature contained in an XML response returned from my SSO/SAML provider in my django/python app, but I can't seem to get it to work.

My XML response looks sort of like the second example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18664/Security-Assertion-Markup-Language-SAML2-0).

**ETA:** And [here's](http://pastebin.com/SqisS4Qv) a pastebin of my actual XML.

I'm using some code like this to attempt the verification:

```
def verify_signature(signed_info, cert, signature):
    from M2Crypto import EVP, RSA, X509

    x509 = X509.load_cert_string(base64.decodestring(cert), X509.FORMAT_DER)
    pubkey = x509.get_pubkey().get_rsa()
    verify_EVP = EVP.PKey()
    verify_EVP.assign_rsa(pubkey)
    verify_EVP.reset_context(md='sha1')
    verify_EVP.verify_init()

    verify_EVP.verify_update(signature.decode('base64'))
    result = verify_EVP.verify_final(signed_info)

    return result
```

I can successfully get the NameID from the response, and I know I'm successfully loading the certificate, because I can pull the issuer, etc. out of it.

As for the signature, though, I've tried hashing the passed in XML, encoding/not encoding various pieces, and passing in various bits of XML for the `signed_info` parameter (the SignedInfo tag, the Response tag, the whole thing), and I've tried using ElementTree/[ElementC14N.py](https://bitbucket.org/effbot/et-2009-provolone/src/35607128f5bb/elementtree/elementtree/ElementC14N.py) to ensure the XML is exclusively canonicalized, as the Transform implies should be done, but I'm not getting a positive result.

What am I missing here?  Am I trying to validate against the wrong XML?  Something wrong with my verification technique?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out @Ennael? Would you mind taking a look at [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21209510/validating-saml-signature-in-python)?

Answer (score 2):

You were so close! You should pass to verify_update the signed_info, and then to verify_final pass the signature.

You do need to make sure that your signed_info is correctly canonicalized before verifying the signature.

Here is the correct method:

```
def verify_signature(signed_info, cert, signature):
    from M2Crypto import EVP, RSA, X509

    x509 = X509.load_cert_string(base64.decodestring(cert), X509.FORMAT_DER)
    pubkey = x509.get_pubkey().get_rsa()
    verify_EVP = EVP.PKey()
    verify_EVP.assign_rsa(pubkey)
    verify_EVP.reset_context(md='sha1')
    verify_EVP.verify_init()

    verify_EVP.verify_update(signed_info)
    result = verify_EVP.verify_final(signature.decode('base64'))

    return result
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll switch back to this project when I get a chance and try it out.

Comment: Sorry to comment on such an old question/answer. Does this verify the SAML token or assertion was un-touched or just verify the signature? I'm unclear if m2crypto is implementing HMAC under the hood and it's just the `verify_update()` value that needs to be expanded?

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I was facing the same problem as you, and found no useful software for validating XML signatures in Python, so I wrote a new library: https://github.com/kislyuk/signxml.

```
from lxml import etree
from signxml import xmldsig

with open("saml2_idp_metadata.xml", "rb") as fh:
    cert = etree.parse(fh).find("//ds:X509Certificate").text

root = ElementTree.fromstring(signature_data)
xmldsig(root).verify(x509_cert=cert)
```