# Validating SAML signature in python

Tags: python, xml, authentication, saml, m2crypto

I need to implement authentication in python from a 3rd party by using SAML2. I have looked into [pysaml2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysaml2/1.1.0) and found that to be quite confusing, and decided to give [M2Crypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/M2Crypto) a chance after I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704919/saml-signature-verification-using-python-m2crypto) by [Ennael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/518959/ennael).

The SAML token I receive [can be found here](http://pastebin.com/vehrUdkB). I have already extracted all the information I need from the `Assertion` tag (the user's SSN, IP and the SAML tokens expiration window) but I can't get the `verify_signature` function from Ennael (and the [revised code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704919/saml-signature-verification-using-python-m2crypto/17372895#17372895) from [Ezra Nugroho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2464942/ezra-nugroho)) to return True. I have also tried to change `verify_EVP.reset_context(md='sha1')` to `verify_EVP.reset_context(md='sha256')` but that didn't work either.

I think my mistake must be in the signed_info part. What do I pass to `verify_signature` for that part? Do I have to preprocess it in any way? I have been looking into the Transform tag but don't know where too look next.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. If someone needs the XML before the obfuscation to test and help me just PM me.

**EDIT** This is my code (very similar to the things i linked to. The main function is at the bottom):

```
def verify_signature(signed_info, cert, signature):
    from M2Crypto import EVP, RSA, X509, m2
    x509 = X509.load_cert_string(base64.decodestring(cert), X509.FORMAT_DER)
    pubkey = x509.get_pubkey().get_rsa()
    verify_EVP = EVP.PKey()
    verify_EVP.assign_rsa(pubkey)
    verify_EVP.reset_context(md='sha1')
    verify_EVP.verify_init()
    verify_EVP.verify_update(signed_info)

    return verify_EVP.verify_final(signature.decode('base64'))

def decode_response(resp):
    return base64.b64decode(resp)

def get_xmldoc(xmlstring):
    return XML(xmlstring)


def get_signature(doc):
    return doc.find('{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}Signature')


def get_signed_info(signature):
    signed_info = signature.find(
        '{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}SignedInfo')
    signed_info_str = tostring(signed_info)
    # return parse(StringIO(signed_info_str))
    return signed_info_str


def get_cert(signature):
    ns = '{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}'
    keyinfo = signature.find('{}KeyInfo'.format(ns))
    keydata = keyinfo.find('{}X509Data'.format(ns))
    certelem = keydata.find('{}X509Certificate'.format(ns))
    return certelem.text


def get_signature_value(signature):
    return signature.find(
        '{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}SignatureValue').text

def parse_saml(saml):
    dec_resp = decode_response(saml)
    xml = get_xmldoc(dec_resp)

    signature = get_signature(xml)
    signed_info = get_signed_info(signature)
    cert = get_cert(signature)
    signature_value = get_signature_value(signature)

    is_valid = verify_signature(signed_info, cert, signature_value)
```

**UPDATE**: Is it possible I need some more information from the 3rd party authentication provider? Do I need a private key for any of this?

Comment: You probably want to show your code so someone can help you.

Comment: Done - thought the links would be enough.

Comment: you don't need anything from 3rd party provider and you don't need private key to check signatures

Comment: Okay, thought as much but wanted to be sure. Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem, and had to develop a module for it: https://github.com/kislyuk/signxml. I chose to rely only on PyCrypto and pyOpenSSL, since M2Crypto is less popular and not well-maintained, which is a hazard from both compatibility (e.g. PyPy) and security perspectives. I also use lxml for the canonicalization (c14n). From the signxml docs:

```
from signxml import xmldsig

cert = open("example.pem").read()
key = open("example.key").read()
root = ElementTree.fromstring(data)
xmldsig(root).verify()
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it tomorrow and let you know how it goes!

Comment: does anyone can help-me with this lib? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33138385/invalid-xml-singnature-using-signxml-python-lib

Comment: Thanks for this library/module. I was able to use it to verify and sign xmls. I have 2 more questions  - 1) This seems to assume that the binding will be http-post. Does this library have any APIs to verify signature for http-redirect? In the redirect case, the SigAlg and Signature are not within the SAML response xml but come as separate parameters in the redirect. 2) This library does not allow me to verify a self signed certificate. Can I work around that?

Comment: @weaver, could you please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77514368/1314503 ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to canonicalize the signed info before validating the signature. That's what the transformation tag implies. Basically, since the same XML can be formatted differently, one needs to validate an XML signature in a canonical format.

Comment: I used [ElementC14N.py](https://bitbucket.org/effbot/et-2009-provolone/src/tip/elementtree/elementtree/ElementC14N.py) and tried to canonicalize the SignedInfo, but it didn't change a thing. You can see, in `get_signed_info` it is commented out (`return parse(StringIO(signed_info_str))`). Is that not correct?

Comment: Per your saml assertion in pastebin, the transformation used should be c14n exclusive; see tag: "<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>"

ElementC14N.py seems to be able to do that, but make sure you are using the right method.